# Batch Script to replace line in an .ini

Tags: batch-file

Please excuse me. I'm a complete noob.

I have 1 ini file with only 1 IP address and a version number.in this format:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
abcde
```

I have 3 total IP's that I need to accommodate. 
I'm looking to create a batch script that will ask a user for a location they'd like to connect to (each location would correspond to an IP address).

> So for example:  NY = 10.0.0.0  DC = 20.0.0.0  LA = 30.0.0.0

The batch would say "Where do you want to connect? 1= NY, 2= DC, 3= LA"
When a user selects 1 for "NY", the script will search the .ini file (which is always in the same location c:\sample) and change the IP to the correct one (10.0.0.0).
It would have an output of something like "You're now connected to NY!"

When a user selects "DC", the script will search the .ini file and change it to 20.0.0.0 etc.I'm able to do a simple find/replace script, but only with 2 IPs, and I had to make one for each location which was rather inconvenient.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: how can the batch know, what IP for  eg. NY?

Comment: You mean a text file? INI files generally have `[sections]` and `key=value`

Answer (score 1):

This example will:

1. Ask user to enter NY, DC or LA;
2. Create x.tmp which is a copy of x.ini, replacing all xxx.xxx... with argument;
3. Replace exisitng x.ini with x.tmp;

Code:

```
@Echo Off

:Begin
If Exist c:\sample\x.tmp Del c:\sample\x.tmp
Set /P "var=Choose location (NY, DC, LA):"
If /I "%var%"=="NY" Call :ReplaceIP 10.0.0.0
If /I "%var%"=="DC" Call :ReplaceIP 20.0.0.0
If /I "%var%"=="LA" Call :ReplaceIP 30.0.0.0
If Exist c:\sample\x.tmp (
    Move /Y c:\sample\x.tmp c:\sample\x.ini 1>Nul
    Echo Success!
) Else (
    Echo Invalid option!
)
Pause
GoTo :Begin

:ReplaceIP
For /F "Tokens=1,2,3,4 Delims=." %%i In (c:\sample\x.ini) do If %%j.==. (
    Echo %%i >> c:\sample\x.tmp
) Else (
    Echo %1 >> c:\sample\x.tmp
)
GoTo :EOF
```

Comment: This is awesome! Would it perhaps be possible to produce a "success message" when the user chooses a location, with a prompt to "Press any key to continue..." where the Key press will again prompt "Choose location"?  I really appreciate the help from everyone...

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out.

```
@echo off
set "var="
set /p "var=Enter 1 for NY, 2 for DC or 3 for LA"
if "%var%" EQU 1 (
  >c:\sample\file.ini echo 10.0.0.0
  >>c:\sample\file.ini abcde
  )
if "%var%" EQU 2 (
  >c:\sample\file.ini echo 20.0.0.0
  >>c:\sample\file.ini abcde
  )
if "%var%" EQU 3 (
  >c:\sample\file.ini echo 30.0.0.0
  >>c:\sample\file.ini abcde
  )
echo Good luck - I hope you entered the right number! :)
```